Why did the general choose this as the exact time of attack?
It is the WWII.
The general ordered his troops to start a surprise attack on the enemy at this exact time:
18:49:06

After the attack which was succssesful some reporters asked him why he chose that exact time. His answer was fascinating.
What was his answer?
This is an original puzzle.

I think he wanted to attack at:

 The right time

If we were to put that time on an analog clock:

 At 18:49:05, the hour and minute hand are 89.6 degrees from each other, and at 18:49:06, they are 90.5 degrees from each other. Somewhere in that second, they are exactly 90 degrees from each other, a right angle.

I'm not entirely satisfied with this answer, but I feel like I'm on the right trail...

 If this is correct, there would be multiple "right" times - 2 per hour! So this doesn't really answer why it's this right time in particular.


rot13 - V trg zhpu pybfre natyrf, vapyhqvat gung rnpu frpbaq jvyy zbir obgu unaqf n fznyy senpgvba bs n qrterr.   V fgvyy qba'g trg gur frpbaq unaq gubhtu, vg vf ryrira qrterrf bss.

rot13 - Svir frpbaqf nsgre vf gur pybfrfg gb nyy guerr sbezvat evtug natyrf naq fvk nsgre jbhyq or fbzr xvaq bs fhecevfr, ohg vs gur cbvag jnf n fhecevfr nggnpx V guvax vg fubhyq or sne sebz n cnggrea naq abg bar frpbaq yngr...

@JasonGoemaat Are these encoded messages?!

You found the right answer DqwertyC!

@EtackSxchange Yes to prevent spoilers...   You can just search 'rot13' for a site to paste the text in to decode it.

@JasonGoemaat The hour hand moves 0.5 degrees every minute. The minute hand moves 6 degrees in the same duration of time. So the hour and minute hands distance themselves 5.5 degrees each minute.
